# How to integrate bootstrap template into rails 4 project

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a bootstrap from http://startbootstrap.com/

and I am trying to integrate it into my application. This template is composed from lots of sub-directories like fonts css, js, font-awesome .. My problem is where to put each directory to be known because there are some files that browser could not read them such as

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/public/font-awesome-4.1.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

knowing that i tried to put font-awesone.. directory under public directory

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is put the parts of the theme in the asset pipeline (app/assets dir), not the public directory. 

**Theme dir => Assets dir**
css => app/assets/stylesheets
img => app/assets/images
fonts => app/assets/fonts
js => app/assets/javascripts

 As [this](http://anotheruiguy.roughdraft.io/7379570-custom-web-fonts-and-the-rails-asset-pipeline) indicates, you do the same for fonts and put them in app/assets/fonts directory.
As a sidenote, i think the site's templates are including basic bootstrap (css/bootstrap.css and css/bootstrap.min.css) and editing it in another file (css/another_theme.css and css/another_theme.min.css), so if i where you i would include bootstrap as a gem in my Gemfile (gem 'bootstrap-sass') and just put the extra files in my asset pipeline.  I'm just saying...